# Some keywords are underlined in VS Code for JAVA

Tags: java, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

[The link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zOhT.png)  I have some keywords underlined in VS Code. They are not wavy but normal underlines. I try restarting it but they are not getting removed. What can I do?

The link is given below

Comment: No link in your question, please edit it and post again. Have a look at [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: If you click on "The link" it will take you there. I am unable to add an image right now

Comment: It should be a feature provided by the current used color themes. Check the color theme settings if it could be disabled. OR you can directly use another color theme, like Dark+(default dark), which is no underline.